# Grep curl elasticsearch output in chef

Tags: ruby, bash, elasticsearch, chef-infra

I need to curl elasticsearch node and to grep the result in chef.

When I try to do it manually on the box it works well - highligts what I need:

```
curl -u 'elastic:xxxxxx' -XGET https://x.x.x.x:9201/_cluster/settings | grep '"node_concurrent_recoveries"\:"100"'
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   141  100   141    0     0  14100      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 14100
{"persistent":{"cluster":{"routing":{"allocation":{"cluster_concurrent_rebalance":"55","node_concurrent_recoveries":"100"}}}},"transient":{}}
```

But when I try to use it in chef it just ignores it:

```
 bash 'set-concurrent-restores-to-100' do
    user 'root'
    code <<-EOC
    echo "setting concurrent restores to 100..."
    curl -u 'elastic:#{node['ElasticPassword']}' -XPUT -H 'Content-Type: application/json' 'https://#{node['fqdn']}:9201/_cluster/settings' -d '{ "persistent": { "cluster.routing.allocation.node_concurrent_recoveries": "100" } }'
    EOC
    not_if "curl -u 'elastic:xxxxx' -XGET https://#{node['fqdn']}:9201/_cluster/settings | grep ''node_concurrent_recoveries'\:'100'' "
  end
```

Chef keeps executing the code even though curl command in `not_if` statement works well.

When I try to grep only "100" then not_if statement works well. So there is definitely an issue with grepping more than one string in my case `"node_concurrent_recoveries":"100" .`

Any idea how to grep this in chef?

Cheers

Comment: Your json has double quotes, but you are grepping single quotes. Of'course it will not find anything.

Comment: @DracoAter if I put double quotes like this ' "node_concurrent_recoveries"\:"100" ' I get rubocopy error E: unexpected token tIDENTIFIER.

Comment: And it highlights ' "node_concurrent_recoveries"\:"100" '

Comment: Well, it's a double quote inside a double quoted string. You need to escape it.

Comment: @DracoAter Can you please advise how to escape? I can try it right away. Cheers

Comment: You must put a backslash before the `"` to escape it.

Comment: I tried with this ' \"node_concurrent_recoveries\"\:\"100\" ' . Chef (rubocop) is not complaining now but still ignores it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace your single quotes in grep (`grep ''node_concurrent_recoveries'\:'100''`) with double quotes, as you have double quotes in json. You can try using ruby [% string literal](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals), so that you don't need to escape a lot of quotes.

```rb
not_if %Q(curl -u 'elastic:xxxxx' -XGET https://#{node['fqdn']}:9201/_cluster/settings | grep '"node_concurrent_recoveries":"100"' )
```

Comment: Brilliant! I just had to go only with % instead of %Q. Thanks for your help